# Check if date is free with SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I need to check if the time that I'm choosing is free.
So as example the time that is between 17:00 - 17:06 is taken and I try to take time that is between 17:01 - 17:07
What would be the right SQL query to check if time is free or taken? Because in this situation 17:01,17:02,17:03 times are taken.

In database I have two fields `laikas` that means the start of the time that is taken(17:00), and `laikas_end` that means the end of taken time(17:07)

As far I got these queries:
To check if the time that I'm taking isn'bt between that time that is taken

```
$uzimtumas_laiko = "SELECT * FROM reklamos WHERE `laikas` >= '$laikas' AND `laikas_end` <= '$laikas_end'";
```

To check if the start time and end time matches (that means it is taken):

```
$uzimtumas_laiko = "SELECT * FROM reklamos WHERE `laikas` = '$laikas' OR `laikas_end` = '$laikas_end'";
```

The situation can be that I try to take time between 16:49 - 17:02, but 17:00 - 17:06 is taken. So 17:50-17:02 can't be chosen. I belive that I need something with BETWEEN but can't think out anything.

Comment: Try this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your start time or end time is in chosen range, so can't chosen:

```
$uzimtumas_laiko = "SELECT * FROM reklamos WHERE (`laikas` BETWEEN '$laikas' AND '$laikas_end') OR (`laikas_end` BETWEEN '$laikas' AND '$laikas_end') OR (`laikas` >= '$laikas' AND `laikas` <= '$laikas_end' ) OR  (`laikas_end` >= '$laikas' AND `laikas_end` <= '$laikas_end' )";
```

Comment: This one works if I try to add 16:49 - 17:02, but If I try to add 17:02-17:03 when 17:01 - 17:07  is taken, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you out

```
"SELECT count(*) as COUNT FROM leave where ((start_date >= to_date(:start_date) and start_date <= to_date(:end_date)) OR (to_date(:start_date) >= start_date and to_date(:start_date) <= end_date)) "
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is a more efficient way to do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM reklamos
WHERE
liakas <= '$liakas_end' AND
liakas_end >= '$liakas'
```

I think of this as checking for an "overlap" between the time slots.